# passing value to onActivityResult

Tags: android

I'm having a problem about passing a value to onActivityResult() method. Here's my code:

```
public class UserUploadActivity extends Activity{

    String userID;
    Uri currImageURI;
    String path;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_upload);
        Bundle gotBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        userID = gotBundle.getString("key");

        Intent selectImageIntent = new Intent();
        selectImageIntent.setType("image/*");
        selectImageIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

       startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(selectImageIntent, "Select Picture"), 1);
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
            // currImageURI is the global variable I’m using to hold the content:
                currImageURI = data.getData();
                path = getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI);
                //covert to base64 image
                Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
                ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
                byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
            //pass the base64 code to string and send it to php file
                String ba1=Base64.encodeBytes(ba);


                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new

                        ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",ba1));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",userID));


                        try{

                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                        HttpPost httppost = new

                        HttpPost("website link");

                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);



                        }catch(Exception e){

                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Hindi Gumana", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }


            }
        }
    }// end method onActivityResult

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri)
    {
        String [] proj={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        android.database.Cursor cursor = managedQuery( contentUri,
        proj,     // Which columns to return
        null,     // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
        null,     // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
        null);     // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }//end method getRealPathFromURI


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_user_upload, menu);
        return true;
    }


    }
```

But my only problem is how to pass the value of userID to onActivityResult. Already posts my entire code. My problem is about intents.

I've already use toast in onCreate method to see its value and its working fine. But whenever I tried it to pass it to onActivityResult, it always returns null.

Comment: you want to use the value of user id in another activity ?

Comment: No. Only in onActivityResult. Because whenever I tried it, it only returns me null.

Comment: Could you also add/show the code where you passing the "key" value to the UserUploadActivity?

Answer (score 0):

If you made userID a class-wide variable, then onActivityResult should have access to it if you override it.

```
public class Blah extends Activity {
    String userID;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        // blah blah
        userID = "whatever value";
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        // use userID
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean I can just put userID inside onActivityResult? I already tried it but it only returns null.

Comment: Can you check that `gotBundle.getString("key")` doesn't return null?

Comment: I've already use toast to see its value and its working fine. But whenever I tried it to pass it to onActivityResult, it always returns null.

Comment: cskoala answers should work. Make userId a class variable. Also, where it is returning null?

Comment: Are you resetting userID in onPause or in any other method... Post your entire activity code

Comment: Already tried a toast inside the onActivityResult but returns null again. Can you briefly explain to me how to use class variables? Maybe that's my problem.

Comment: To use the class variable just follow the sample code I provided. Place it outside of any methods, but within your class. Then the variable will have class scope and can be used anywhere in that class.

Comment: Can you verify that `gotBundle.getString("key")` doesn't return null? I think that may be the problem since that's where you set the value of userID.

Comment: That's not the problem sir because I already call a toast on onCreate method and it returns me the right value. I'm already searching for an answer in 3 hours, hope that you can help me.

Comment: its a weird problem. Can you put the logcat info here? if it can help.

Comment: Yeah, logcat would be helpful or if you know the exact line that's causing the NullPointerException.

Comment: Based on my research,intent values that startActivityForResult method get is returned by onActivityResult. This code can already upload images from android to server, but i need the value of user's id for the database. I really need help.

Comment: I tried your code.. It is working for me. I dont know what is happening on your side

Comment: code looks fine. The only thing that may help us now is the logcat. once post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling this activity from another. And the bundle you are receiving do not contain the "userId" token I suspect.

userID = gotBundle.getString("key");

This is the only place you are using your userID. You should be able to access the value if you are receiving the "key". 
Put a sysout or toast soon after the above line.

Comment: userID's value come from another activity. When I put a toast on the onCreate method, it returns the correct value, but when I use it on onActivityResult method, it returns me 0.

Comment: Hey phxjames, I just tried your activity code.. It is working for me... The only change what i did was i hardcoded the userId. userID = "saneesh ";//gotBundle.getString("key"); Try harcoding the userId in onCreate. If it is working, issue will be with gotBundle.getString("key");

Comment: It's also working for me sir. But it is strange that when I use gotBundle.getString("key") it's not working on the onActivityResult but working on the onCreate. Is there any other way to pass value from activity to other activity that can work on onActivityResult?

Comment: There is no difference in hardcoding the value for "userId" or reading it from gotBundle.getString("key"). It is nothing but setting the value for userID. If it is not working, then it is a problem in setting extra value for "key" when you invoke UserUploadActivity. One more thing, you are not passing any value to onActivityResult. You are just accessing the global variable userID.

Comment: You told us that you showed a toast in oncreate to check userID. Can you post that code. Also please post the code how you are accessing userID in onActivityResult method.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a chance that your process will be terminated while your intent starts to get content, you need to hold onto that information in the saved instance state Bundle, so that you can get it back when your activity gets re-created.

first save userID in onSaveInstanceState....

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the userID.
    savedInstanceState.putString("myKey", userID);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Then in onCreate method get userID as below

```
if(savedInstanceState != null) {
       urerID = savedInstanceState.getString("myKey");
}
```

after doing this you will be able to get userID in onActivityResult. I had the same issue like your's when i tried this it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question, I realize, but I think the issue here is that the Intent passed to `onActivityResult()` is not necessarily the same one passed to `startActivityForResult`. That's the case with the camera activity, at least. (It creates a new Intent for the result.)

The documentation I've found is far from clear on this, but it looks to me like the *only* piece of information you can pass *through* the Activity call (and get back in `onActivityResult`) is the integer `requestCode`. If you can't capture your data in an integer, maybe you can use it as a key for a Map kept by the calling class.

Or do what I suspect most people do: put the `userId` in an instance variable of the Activity, and retrieve it in `onActivityResult`. (And if the caller is an Activity, you should also do as [Hidayat Ullah's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53216856/686385) suggests and save the field value in the Activity saved instance state.)

Update: [Another answer that says the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45247229/686385)