# How to pass intent extras to onactivityresult when activity reboot?

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

I am writing an android application. Need to pass int value.I have a listview that it has contextmenu.I must start Intent.Action_Call. When I start my intent. My application is going to background. When intent is finish my application start a survey.My problem is ;I am not getting user"s clicked position.I tried insert to putExtra but in onActivityResult void does not accepted value of my user"s clicked position and value become zero.How can I get ıt ?

```
   public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        selectedPosition = info.position;

     //in here , this value is true.
            Toast.makeText(AnaMenu.this, String.valueOf(selectedPosition), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case MENU_Ara:

                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    final ArrayList<String> secilmis = i.getStringArrayListExtra("listem");

                    Intent ara = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    ara.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + secilmis.get(info.position).toString()));


                    ara.putExtra("selected", selectedPosition);





                    startActivityForResult(ara, AnketDegerlendirmesi);






                    return true;
            }


            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }




     protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {

            if (requestCode == AnketDegerlendirmesi){
                Toast.makeText(AnaMenu.this,String.valueOf(selectedPosition),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                final AlertDialog.Builder  mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AnaMenu.this);
                mBuilder.setTitle("Deger");
                mBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_build_black_24dp);
                mBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(afteractivitydialogitems, dialogcheckeditems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position, boolean isChecked) {



                        if (isChecked){
        mUserselecteditems.add(Integer.valueOf(dialogdegerleri[position]));
    }
    if (!isChecked) {
    if (mUserselecteditems.contains(Integer.valueOf(dialogdegerleri[position]))){
        mUserselecteditems.remove(Integer.valueOf(dialogdegerleri[position]));
    }
    }
     }
                });

                mBuilder.setCancelable(false);
                mBuilder.setPositiveButton("Tamamdır.", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                        String items = "";
                        toplamaislemi = 0;
                        for (int item : mUserselecteditems) {
                            items += "-" + item + "\n";

                            toplamaislemi = toplamaislemi + item;



   //When i want to get this value.Value is always zero(0)
                        String returnString = data.getStringExtra("selected");
                        kullanıcısayıdegerlistesi.remove(String.valueOf(returnString));
                        kullanıcısayıdegerlistesi.add(Integer.valueOf(returnString),String.valueOf(toplamaislemi));
                        oyunTextView.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                }  )             .show();


            }


            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, put this on onContextItemSelected

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.clear();

                editor.putInt("kelime", selectedPosition);

                editor.commit();
```

After Settle down above cod,Set onActivityResult

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    int selec = settings.getInt("kelime",selectedPosition);
```

Finally, set the adapter same void :

```
kullanıcısayıdegerlistesi.remove(selec);
                        kullanıcısayıdegerlistesi.add(selec ,String.valueOf(sonuc));
```

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're expecting to be able to call this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(...);
i.putExtra("some_key", someValue);
startActivityForResult(i, requestCode);
```

and then later, when you receive the result:

```
protected void onActivityResult(... Intent data) {
    data.getExtra("some_key"); // should be `someValue` from above
}
```

Unfortunately, this is not how it works. The `Intent data` argument to `onActivityResult()` is not the same `Intent` that you used to start that activity. The activity that you started has complete control over whether the `data` intent is non-null, and what's inside of it.

Usually for public APIs, there is documentation about what you can expect to have inside the `data` intent.

Comment: Ok.So i cant achive this selectedPosition.But how can I get it ? if i have to create date base I do .My application's purpose is user"s click listview and call the number then setting new value to listview that when phone call is ended. show you survey..If you have any document for this topic.Please share it.It must found the way.

Comment: You can either record the value at the time of the click somehow (e.g. shared preferences, database, or even just a variable in your activity) and then use that value in `onActivityResult()`, or you can encode the value you need to save into your requestCode (e.g. use bitmasks).

Comment: how to encode value into my requestCode. İf it doesnt work I am going to shared preferences tag.I understood.

Comment: Essentially, you use some of the bits of the `requestCode` as the true request code and some of the bits to represent your position. Imagine that you know that `selectedPosition` will always be <= 4095 (i.e. 0xfff). You could call `startActivityForResult(intent, 0xf000 | selectedPosition)` and then in `onActivityResult()` say `if (requestCode & 0xf000 == 0xf000)` (this identifies it as being your request) and then `selectedPosition = (requestCode & 0x0fff);`

Comment: I almost get it.How can I  understand this requestCode happens?Do you have any  books, website ,link , where is in this web-site?What is the tag name ? Because I havent got anything about manipulting requestcode.And yes I understood what i have to do.

Comment: I am very very thanks.All your comment. I am grateful for this.I add to how to solve this problem.